# human-friendly URL with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url

I am developing web with Codeigniter. I what the url like this:

[site]/[company_name]. The [company_name] is dynamic.

For example: http://www.abc.com/alixa

But the real url is: http://www.abc.com/shop/alixa

Is there anyway can I do with this? with htaccess or route in codeigniter?

Answer (score 0):

Yap you can do it from both .htaccess and routes

here is solution from using routes

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'shop/$1';
```

by using this route you will getting problem from other url as if you wants
 http://www.abc.com/mysecoundController/myfunction
it will also redirect to shop controller,
  For this you have to write more routes 
as

```
     $route['(mySecoundController:any)'] = 'mySecoundController/$1';
     $route['(:any)'] = 'shop/$1';
```

here is the link for detail
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check this article that include all the information that you need: http://www.web-and-development.com/codeigniter-minimize-url-and-remove-index-php/#removing-first-url-segment